# PyDev installation not working. No editor. No preferences

Tags: python, linux, eclipse, pydev, java-7

Hope it helps someone else.

So the problem I had was:

I installed PyDev into Eclipse Kepler using Eclipse Marketplace. Everything goes on fine and ends successfully. But PyDev doesn't show up anywhere after restart. E.g. no Python Editor, No "PyDev" in the preferences, no PyDev perspective, ... It's as if PyDev isn't installed. The only place where it shows up is in the Eclipse Maretplace where I can see it under installed tab.

Tried to reinstall (uninstall from Marketplace) via update site. Same result.

I was using Java 1.6 with Eclipse Kepler and installing latest version of PyDev 3.3.3.

No errors reported in eclipse logs.

Comment: Rather than having both eclipse and eclipse-kepler, do you think you could tag your OS in place of one of those?

Comment: Done. Though it's relevant to all OSs.

Answer (score 1):

Problems were:

1. My eclipse folder was in /opt and owned by root.
2. PyDev 3.3.3 needs java 1.7. Quote [from their site](http://pydev.org/manual_101_install.html).

> PyDev now requires java 7 in order to run. If you don't have java 7,
>   the update process may appear to succeed, but PyDev will simply not
>   show in the target installation.

Soln:

- Use JDK 1.7: [Add -vm option to eclipse.ini](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM) (in eclipse install-root folder) to specify path to `java` executable inside JDK 1.7. Note the JDK (not JRE). Param can be passed on command line as well but I recommend adding to ini file.

e.g. in my case I added this above the `-vmargs` in `eclipse.ini` file.

```
-vm
/opt/java/jdk1.7.0_45-x64/bin/java
```

- Run eclipse as the user that owns eclipse folder (`root` in my case)
- Install PyDev somehow, e.g. Search in Eclipse Marketplace or add `http://pydev.org/updates` to update sites in Help->Install New software. Or get teh zip file.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Debian Jessie . Eclipse Mars 4.1 .
I installed whilst my java environment was set to /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java and after the restart no reference to the PyDev install could be found other than in the installation details.

After Changing to java 1.8 ( sudo update-alternatives --config java ) and restarting eclipse all PyDev components appeared.